# How do I get all possible end points at the middle ware level?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, log4net, middleware

I am working on writing some generic middleware for a few APIs. I want this middleware to write to a log file when the request has a valid endpoint and will hit an action on my controller.

Comment: May be it will be simpler to log it afterwards,? This may help if applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604609/net-core-endrequest-middleware

Comment: Take an inventory of the endpoints. Read the API documentation. Examine the API source code. Etc?

Comment: This answer might be helpful to get all possible api endpoints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56383821/9381487